# Understanding MultipartFile transferTo() method in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring Framework's MultipartFile to allow a user to upload a picture to a profile. I've configured DispatcherServlet in a servlet initializer class that extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer. In that class, I've overridden the customizeRegistration() method as follows:

```
@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) {
    registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp/practicewellness/uploads", 2097152, 4194304, 0));
}
```

The MultipartFile's transferTo() method calls for a file location in the filesystem where the uploaded file will be written temporarily. Can this location be anywhere? When I used the following location in the method:

```
profilePicture.transferTo(new File("tmp/practicewellness/" + employee.getUsername() + ".jpg"));
```

... I get the following error:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: The temporary upload location [C:\Users\kyle\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\work\Catalina\localhost\practicewellness\tmp\practicewellness\uploads] is not valid
```

So I can see that it's looking for this file location deep inside one of my Eclipse plugins. I don't understand why it looks there. When I look there, the "tmp" directory is not there. But regardless, is it okay for me to go into that plugin and create the directory there? Or is there a better way to smooth this out?

Comment: Did that path even exist? If you want to create the folder if it didn't exist, you have to use mkdir

Answer (score 3):

I've uploaded files using Spring mvc, but never used transferTo(), I just assume that your problem is due to "No existence of specified path" because there wont be a path ending with .jpg. Try it like this.

```
String path = "/tmp/practicewellness/";
File dirPath = new File(path);
if (!dirPath.exists()) {
        dirPath.mkdirs();     
}
```

And then execute the transferTo() code.
Also do not set the path directly like you've done. Since you're doing it in spring, so I assume you want the folder to be in your Project path not the eclipse's metadata path. So change your path to this.

```
String path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/tmp/practicewellness/");
```

It will create a folder inside your Project's Webapp folder using mkdir. If you want to save differentiate the files for each user, you can create a folder for each user by using this below path.

```
String path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/tmp/practicewellness")+"/"+employee.getUsername()+"/";
```

Comment: I apologize for not marking this as the answer. I haven't tried your solution because I'm backing away from adding the file upload feature. It's a level of complexity I'm not quite ready, as a newbie, to implement. But I'd like to leave this question intact for others who may be having this same issue.

Comment: No problem kyle. Upload feature is not a big deal, if you need any assistance or tutorial examples for file upload in Spring MVC, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old, but I just wanted to add: the path you're transferring to is relative. Better idea is to use an absolute path.

Anyway, transferTo(File) is a perfect method. The problem with multipart file upload is that you have not so much control over where the stream goes when it arrives on the server over HTTP. By definition it works in 2 steps, first file upload will store it in a temp file (out of your control), and then it is up to you to consume it in the file upload callback either by reading the stream out or by transferring it to a location totally in your control. The advantage of transferring is that it takes virtually no time compared to reading the stream (which will block the upload HTTP request).

**Caution to make sure you pass in a File argument (and not a Path). Seems like a very bad idea to have overloaded methods like this with quite different implementations. Passing in a Path will always execute a streamed copy!**